# Avoid duplicate code with inversion of control

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, architecture, inversion-of-control

I have the following implementation

```
public class ContextService : IContextService
{
    private readonly ICacheProvider _cache;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ContextService(ICacheProvider cache, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public string GetAuthToken()
    {
        // Logic to obtain an auth token
        // ...

        // Code that must be executed if we're running on a dev machine
        InitializeContextInLocalEnvironment(auth.Token);

        return auth.Token;
    }
}
```

The problem is the method `InitializeContextInLocalEnvironment(string)`. It runs some stuff when the code runs on a developers machine, but doesn't when running somewhere else (eg. test server).

With inversion of control I would create another implementation of `IContextService`, right? Which is injected only when the code runs on a dev machine. I can do this by organizing my bindings in a module (Autofac). But with that new implementation I would introduce duplicate code, because I need all the stuff from the `ContextService` class, **plus** the logic from the `InitializeContextInLocalEnvironment(string)` method.

What am I missing?

Comment: Having a get method with side-effects is a very bad design.The solution is rather simple, either using inheritance with an abstract `AContextService` class with an abstract `Initialize()` method or using composition with an `IContextInitializer` interface that gets injected in `ContextService`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not subclassing your ContextService and overwrite GetAuth? Make an abstract class with all your content from ContextService and implement the differences.

Comment: Yes, this would reduce code duplication for the other methods in `ContextService`. But for the `GetAuthToken()` method I would still need to add the exact same logic in the subclass inside the overriding method.